# TeeChart VCL - Add Marks

Tags: delphi, charts, series, vcl, teechart

I'm trying to create a aditional mark from TDonutSeries at runtime.
I have used this source code below:

```
   with Series1.Marks.Children.Add do
   begin
      Shape.Font.Size:= 10;
      Shape.ShapeStyle:= fosRectangle;
      Shape.Style:= smsPercent;
   end;
```

In this line

```
Shape.Style = smsPercent;
```

I received this error: 
**E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'style'**

Is there any way to set the style for the specific mark item or I need to use a specific unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to `TSeriesMarkShape` to access the `Style` property. Ie:

```
  with Series1.Marks.Children.Add do
  begin
    Shape.Font.Size:= 10;
    Shape.ShapeStyle:= fosRectangle;
    TSeriesMarkShape(Shape).Style:= smsPercent;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Style` property for `TTextShape` object. But you can use `OnGetMarkText` event to output mark labels in own custom format.

Comment: But in my case, I need to create more than one Mark item (like as possible to do on design time in Series/Series1//Marks/Text/ button +) . In this method OnGetMarkText I have access to main mark text item. Is there any way to manipulate the child mark item? Thanks for your attention.